# Mapping Ctrl+[ and Ctrl+] to move between buffers in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to move between buffers.

I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <c-[> :bprevious<CR>
nnoremap <c-]> :bnext<CR>
nnoremap <Esc> :noh<CR>
```

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> works. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> trigger an `:noh` and I don't know why.

I would like to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> simply move between buffers and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to trigger an `:nho`.

Comment: In many terminals, `c-[` is equivalent to `Esc`, which explains the `:noh` being triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd> are already being used by `vim`. Mapping keys which are already being used by `vim` is not recommended. 
More at `:help map-which-keys`.

So, instead of mapping those keys, I would like to suggest, for example,  to use <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
nnoremap <F2> :bprevious<CR>
nnoremap <F3> :bnext<CR>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understood correctly. I'm opening each file in a buffer, not using tabs (at least not right now). Your suggestion is to open each file in a tab instead of a buffer?

Comment: Oh, I thought it is tabs. I need to modify the answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 3):

@dlmeetei and @Lucas Beier are correct. These are poor keys for Vim.

Map safe keys like function keys, leader mappings, or unused mappings. Example (same as [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired)):

```
nnoremap [b :bprevious<c>r
nnoremap ]b :bnext<cr>
nnoremap ]B :blast<cr>
nnoremap [B :bfirst<cr>
```

For more help see:

```
:h map-which-keys
:h key-notation
:h :bfirst
:h :blast
```

#### We can do better! or The problem with cycling buffers

Cycling buffers is kind slow. I believe `:bprevious` and `:bnext` are only useful in a narrow set of conditions:

- These commands become useful after you use more than 2 buffers (probably due to `<c-6>`/`<c-^>`).
- Once you hit a certain buffer number threshold, there is sort of an upper limit on the usefulness of cycling with these commands. Is it faster to cycle forward? Backwards? Does it matter because it simply takes too long either way?

Instead of cycling with `:bp` and `:bn` you can jump directly to a buffer via `:b` command. Simply use `:b {partial_name}<tab>`.

#### Behold the power of `:b`:

- Uses `<tab>` completion
- Use `<c-d>` to list out completion
- Use partial file name. e.g. `:b foo`. Works great with `<tab>`.
- Globbing. e.g. `:b foo*bar` or `:b foo/**/bar`
- Split variant of `:b` is `:sb`.
- Also accepts a buffer number
- A common mapping: `nnoremap <leader>b :ls<cr>:b<space>`

For more help see:

```
:h :b
:h :ls
:h cmdline-completion
:h file-searching
```

#### Can we do better than `:b`?

Skip the buffer management completely and use tags, cscope, and/or [GNU Global](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/). These will help you go directly to where you want to go not just the right buffer with where ever you last left the cursor.

For beginners to tags I suggest [Gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags) and `:h tags`.

You can also use `:find` with tab completion and set your `'path'` to `.,,**` for a basic less fuzzy finder.

For more help see:

```
:h CTRL-]
:h tags
:h cscope
:h :find
:h 'path'
```

#### Plugins?

A fuzzy finder like [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) or [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) allows for general file navigation. For more specific project navigation you can use something like [Projectionist.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist).

#### Conclusion

I would suggest slowly learning more buffer and general navigation commands. These commands will serve you well and help you navigation quicker without resorting to buffer cycling.

Personally, I use a combination of `:b`, tags, cscope/GNU Global, and projectionist.vim for most of my navigation needs. I often have over 50+ buffers open and get to my desired file without ever resorting to buffer cycling.